# PHP Echo Appearing Twice

Tags: php, echo

I am trying to show an echo when a user improperly enters their license key, though, for some reason, the message appears twice.

```
    $invalidkey = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>
            <html>
                <body>
                    <center>
                    <div class="container2"
                        <h1>Your Product Key is Invalid!</h1>
                    </div>
                    </center>
                </body>
            </html>
            ';

if ($resulto->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = $resulto->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $user_group = $row["LicenseKey"];
        $days = $row["Count"];
        // Key is valid
        if ($user_group == $key)
        {
            $keyvalidated = true;
            echo $user_group;
            echo $key;

        }
        // Key is invalid
        else if ($usergroup !== $key)
        {
            echo $invalidkey;
            $keyvalidated = false;
        }    
    }
}
```

Here is an image of the error actually appearing:
 [image]

Comment: perhaps you have 2 results, so 2 lopps,

Comment: Because it is inside the loop, then it runs twice... change your `while loop condition`

Comment: I wouldn't echo an entire HTML document into what I can only assume is already a partial HTML document. That's going to cause you some rendering problems even after you solve this one.

Comment: What is `$usergroup` and what is `$key`. How many rows are in your result-set?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that for whatever reason there are actually two records in the result set.  The best fix would be to find a way to run the right query, which just returns a single record for a single user.  As a quick fix, perhaps just check the first record:

```
if ($resulto->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $resulto->fetch_assoc();
    $user_group = $row["LicenseKey"];
    $days = $row["Count"];
    // Key is valid
    if ($user_group == $key) {
        $keyvalidated = true;
        echo $user_group;
        echo $key;
    }
    // Key is invalid
    else if ($usergroup !== $key) {
        echo $invalidkey;
        $keyvalidated = false;
    }    
}
```

Again, you need to find out why the result set has two, or more than one, records.

Comment: The quick fix might mean that unexpected results occur, because the wrong record is always selected and the user's data isn't properly validated.

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding a break since there could be more than one iteration (or you wouldn't need a loop):

```
// Key is invalid
else if ($usergroup !== $key)
{
    echo $invalidkey;
    $keyvalidated = false;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's showing 2 times is because query is fetching 2 results. So you need to limit query to just 1, just read the first record, or break the loop after 1st iteration.

```
while($row = $resulto->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $user_group = $row["LicenseKey"];
    $days = $row["Count"];
    // Key is valid
    if ($user_group == $key)
    {
        $keyvalidated = true;
        echo $user_group;
        echo $key;

    }
    // Key is invalid
    else if ($usergroup !== $key)
    {
        echo $invalidkey;
        $keyvalidated = false;
    }    

    break;
}
```